# What is the best java based CSV parser for parsing bank statements?

Tags: java, parsing, csv

What is the best CSV java library to parse bank statements. Is there any standard csv format for bank statements? Where can i get the sample files?

Comment: It's been asked (and answered) MANY times on SO how to read CSV files. Just have a look at Related section on the right. And I think you saw many suggestions above when you were writing this question.

Comment: If someone land on this page, here is comparison of various different parsers performances https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison

Answer (score 0):

I use openCSV.

Very easy to use, see the examples:

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read

Answer (score 0):

Parsing bank statements in csv is as good as parsing any other csv file.

I always rely on [OpenCsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: in average 73% percent slower than uniVocity..